# Problem with MulticastSocket on Java-Android

Tags: java, android, multicastsocket

I'm starting to code with MulticastSocket, trying to make a simple app with a client and a server to send messages.

The code I have for the server:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.MulticastSocket;
    import java.net.SocketException;


    public class Servidor {
 private static MulticastSocket ms;
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

  InetAddress sessAddr = InetAddress.getByName("224.2.76.24");
     try{
    sessAddr = InetAddress.getByName("224.2.76.24");
       ms = new MulticastSocket(5500);
       ms.joinGroup(sessAddr);

       while (true)
       {
       byte[] mensaje = new byte[1024];
       mensaje = "aa".getBytes();
       DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(mensaje, mensaje.length,sessAddr,5500);
       ms.send(dp);
       }
      }
      catch (SocketException se) {
        System.err.println(se);
      }

      ms.leaveGroup(sessAddr);

    }

}
```

And this on the client:

```
    package com.example;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.MulticastSocket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ClienteMultiCast extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView Mensaje;
        Mensaje =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Mensaje);


        InetAddress ia = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65535];
        MulticastSocket ms = null;
        int port = 5500;
        try {
        ia = InetAddress.getByName("224.2.76.24");
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,ia,port);
        ms = new MulticastSocket(port);
            ms.joinGroup(ia);
            while (true) {
                ms.receive(dp);
                String s = new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength());
                Mensaje.setText(s);
            }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {Mensaje.setText(e.getMessage());} catch (IOException e) {Mensaje.setText(e.getMessage()); }

            try {
            ms.leaveGroup(ia);
             } catch (IOException e) {
            Mensaje.setText(e.getMessage());
  }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I start both, nothing happens. The client doesn't get any message.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Could you give some info into the deployment of the app? This might be a network setup issue. UDP and UDP-Multicast specifically work best within the same physical network. UDP Multicast could be configured to be blocked by the upper level gateways. If you are doing this over the data network of two phones I would be surprised if any service provider would allow UDP multicast traffic to adhoc groups. Have you tried this with the phones on the same physical network like over the same wifi access point of two emulators on the same host?

Answer (score 8):

Diego,

By default, the Android WiFi stack filters out multicast packets. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html.

You need something along the lines of:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Turn off multicast filter */
    MulticastLock mcastLock = new MulticastLock();
    mcastLock.acquire();

    /* Process Multicast Packets */

  }
```

Comment: Actually, that won't work out of the box, as the MulticastLock() method has no public constructor.  You need to do it like this: WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiManager.MulticastLock multicastLock = wm.createMulticastLock("mydebuginfo");
multicastLock.acquire(); (Kudos to this site for clarifying the info for me: http://www.whizzosoftware.com/forums/blog/1/entry-40-android-jmdns-and-wifi-multicast-packets/)

Comment: And you need this permission in your manifest too: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />

Comment: And you have to do what Steve said in front of super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Multicast support in Android is not as solid as some of use might hope. See http://codeisland.org/2012/udp-multicast-on-android/

Ie whether it actually works out or may be device dependent. It is not working on my Nexus5.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=51195